# how tell to a function to wait the end of animation of another function

Tags: jquery, wait

I have two functions here say animation1 and load1 they work like that:

```
function animation1() {
    element.animate({width(size)});
}
```

and

```
function load1() {
    element.find('img').after(newImg)
}
```

there's a click event who fires both, but how can I tell to load1 to wait until animation 1 has finished the animation and then add the newImg element? I know I can callback load1 into animate() of animation1, but I've separate one from another because I'm reusing animation1 in a lot of places. What happens now is that both are fired together, and it's not nice to the eyes.

thank you

d.

Comment: In `element.animate({width(size)});`, you're **calling** a `width` function, passing in a `size` argument, and then trying to put its return value inside `{}` as a parameter to `animate`. I'm fairly sure that's a syntax error, did you mean `element.animate({width: size});`?

Comment: sure, it's just a quick example. I'm trying to tell to Load1 to wait until animation1 has finished his animation, do his .after method. This in the case that both are fired togheter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

#### Use a callback

I know you've said

> I know I can callback load1 into animate() of animation1, but I've separate one from another because I'm reusing animation1 in a lot of places.

...but a callback really is the best way to do this. In the places where you don't need a callback, just don't pass one to `animation1`.

Modify `animation1` to accept a callback, which it passes to the `animate` function, which accepts a "completion" callback it fires when the animation is complete:

```
function animation1(callback) {
    // See also my comment on the question regarding `{width(size)}`
    element.animate({width: size}, callback);
}
```

...and then your click would pass in a reference to `load1` to `animation1` rather than calling it directly, like this:

```
function clickHandler() {
    animation1(load1);
}
```

See the [`animate` docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for details of the completion function.

#### Use a timer

If you tell `animation1` exactly how long to take, you could use `setTimeout` to delay your call to `load1`:

```
function animation1(duration) {
    // See also my comment on the question regarding `{width(size)}`
    element.animate({width: size}, duration);
}
```

...and then your click would pass in a duration to `animation1` and use `setTimeout` to delay calling `load` by the same amount:

```
function clickHandler() {
    animation1(400);
    setTimeout(load1, 400);
}
```

Of the two, I'd definitely go for the callback rather than the `setTimeout` barring some other design constraint.

Comment: after reading all your suggestions I think that using a callback it's the best way to achieve this. Thanks everybody!

d.

Answer (score 0):

You are "using animation1 in lots of places" but you want it to behave differently in terms of the funciton flow? Souds like you need a separate function animation2 which can include the callback. Reuse is an excellent idea in general, but you are actually doing something different here, because you are animating AND THEN something.

Comment: maybe this could be the case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's animate function has a `callback` function that you can use for this. You can use it in various different ways. The easiest for the example you've given is probably to use a global variable:

```
var isAnimating = false;

function animation1(){
  isAnimating = true;
  element.animate({width(size)}, function(){ isAnimating=false; });
}

function load1(){
  if(isAnimating){
    load1(); // call again
  }
  else {
    element.find('img').after(newImg);
  }
}
```

However this isn't very efficient - load1() will keep running in a perpetual loop until `isAnimating` is false. A better option is therefore to use the callback to actually call load1...

```
function animate1(){
  element.animate({width(size)}, function() { load1(); });
}

function load1(){
  element.find('img').after(newImg);
}
```

This can be expanded incase you need to call different functions for each...

```
function animate1(callback){
  element.animate({width(size)}, function() {
    var fn = window[callback];
    if(typeof fn === 'function') {
      fn();
    }
  });
}
```